# Create a border around 2 divs

Tags: html, css

Just a quick question...

I have created two divs - essentially two squares, one large one small - positioned one beneath another.

[image]

I would like to put a border around both of these divs to outline the entire shape - not an outline around both divs as I have done in the picture - It leaves the line between which I have circled in the image. Is this possible?

Here is the the html and css for the divs:

```css
#shapeTop {
  height: 70px; 
  width: 70px; 
  background: blue; 
  float: right; 
  outline: 4px solid black;
}
 
 #shapeBottom {
  height: 420px; 
  width: 420px; 
  background: blue; 
  clear: both; 
  float: right; 
  outline: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape">
  <div id="shapeTop">
  </div>
  
  <div id="shapeBottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance - G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `border` instead, disable the bottom border on the top box, add `position: relative` to the top box so it displays on top of the bottom one, and use `translateY()` to push the top box down 4 px so it covers the bottom box's border.

```css
#shapeTop {
  height: 70px; 
  width: 70px; 
  background: blue; 
  float: right; 
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 4px 4px 0;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
 
 #shapeBottom {
  height: 420px; 
  width: 420px; 
  background: blue; 
  clear: both; 
  float: right; 
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape">
  <div id="shapeTop">
  </div>
  
  <div id="shapeBottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Great answer

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just set the `border-bottom` property to 0px, or none, for the top box (and convert all the `outlines` to `borders`).

Then, set `border-top` for the bottom box to none as well.

Finally, add a :before pseudo element to the bottom box (you also have to set `position: relative;` on the bottom box). This :before element should contain the following code:

```
#bottomBox:before {
content: ""; // needed any :before element
position: absolute; // needed for following code
left: 0; // 
top: 0;  // sets it to start at the top left
height: 2px; /*  thickness of border */
width: 150px; /* adjust this until its the correct length */
background-color: black; /* color of border */

}
```

Answer (score -1):

setting border-bottom to 0px will not remove border-top from the big square, I recommend to set: border-bottom: 5px solid blue; and have #shapeTop below #shapeBottom and have that property in the last line - in that case it will overwrite everything above.